# Where do edited questions with downvotes appear in question lists?

Tags: support, questions, edits

If I edit my own downvoted questions, then what would happen? Does it gets higher acceptance probability?

In which section of the question list would it be displayed? In Hot, Monthly, etc?

Comment: "*then what would happen does it gets accepted?*" What you you mean by "does it get accepted?" Do you mean, does the question become acceptable to Stack Overflow's guidelines?

Comment: "*Does it gets probability of higher acceptance?*" That still doesn't make sense. What does it mean for a question to be "accepted"? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They get bumped to the front page, as with any other question.

The only situation in which a question will not be visible on the front page, even when it gets bumped by editing, is when the question's score is less than -4, the threshold required for a question to show up on the front page.